# how to return related entities from wcf dataservice

Tags: json, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I created a WCF dataservice class to return query results to javascript client. Here's the pseudocode for my dataservice:

```
public class MyDataService : DataService<MyEntities>
{
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("MyGetMethod", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServicePRotocolVersion.V2;
    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{SomeID}"]
    public IEnumerable<Models.Customer> MyGetMethod(int? someID)
    {
        if (someID == null) throw new DataServiceException("ID not specified");

        MyEntities context = this.CurrentDataSource;
        context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        var q = Linq statement which queries for a collection of entities from context

        IEnumerable<Models.Customer> result = q;
        foreach (Models.Customer customer in result)
        {
            if (!customer.Contacts.IsLoaded)
                customer.Contacts.Load();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The call from the client requests result in json. When I debug the get method in dataservice, result has the specific related data expanded in a property called WrappedRelatedEntities, but in the json returned to the client, for that related entity it said deferred.

What do I need to do to have those related entities returned to client? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WCF DS Service there's no way the server can force-expand a navigation property. It only works if the client asks for it. So change your service operation to return IQueryable and then the client needs to add $expand=NameOfThePropertyToExpand to the URL.